# PDF reader to display 2 pages in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, pdf

I am iPhone application developer,
I want to develop application part to display PDF file.

I want to disply pages such that,

> - Application will use landscape mode only and
> - Two pages are displayed at a time.

I tried using vrf reader : https://github.com/vfr/Reader

> - But not succeed for displaying 2 pages at a time.

Is there any way or library or demo for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) to display 2 pages in landscape mode. Check this [tutorial](http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-uipageviewcontroller-programatically-without-storyboarding/):